# QtCore.QObject.connect in a loop only affects the last instance

Tags: python, qt, lambda, pyqt, signals-slots

I have got a loop. I created a `QCheckBox` and put it in a `QTableWidget` cell, and everything is Ok. In each step of loop I have called a `connect` function, for myslot SLOT, but only the last `QCheckBox` instance is applied. I googled a lot and have found many people have my problem. I have  applied their solutions, but my problem remains.

```
for row in xrange(len(uniqueFields)):
    instance = QtGui.QCheckBox(uniqueFields[row], findInstance.tableWidget)
    print QtCore.QObject.connect(instance,
        QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("stateChanged (int)")),
        lambda: findInstance.projectsInstance.myslot(
                    "TWCH", findInstance, instance.text(),
                    instance.checkState(), instance))
    findInstance.tableWidget.setRowCount(findInstance.tableWidget.rowCount() + 1)
    findInstance.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, instance)
```

**Note:** my `connect` function return `True`.

How to create `connect` function in a loop that enumerates all of the `instances`?

Comment: I have no idea why this question was tagged C++. It's clearly Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem , you should use `functools.partial` such as:

```
for key, val in a_DICT_THAT_YOU_STORED_YOUR_OBJECTS_AND_STRINGS:
    obj = partial(   findInstance.projectsInstance.myslot,arg1="TWCH",arg2=self,arg3=key,arg4=val.checkState() )
    QtCore.QObject.connect(val, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("stateChanged (int)")), obj)
```

Of course, argX should set to your real name of your argument of your function name.

Answer (score 7):

Put the loop variable in a default argument, like this:

```
lambda state, instance=instance: findInstance.projectsInstance.myslot(
    "TWCH", findInstance, instance.text(), instance.checkState(), instance)
```

This will give each `lambda` its own local copy of the `instance` variable.

**EDIT**

Here's a simple script that demonstrates how to use default lambda arguments:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        for index in range(4):
            instance = QtGui.QCheckBox('Checkbox(%d)' % index, self)
            instance.stateChanged.connect(
                lambda state, instance=instance:
                    self.mySlot(instance.text()))
            layout.addWidget(instance)

    def mySlot(self, text):
        print('clicked: %s' % text)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That doesn't work because no arguments are passed to the slot when the signal is emitted. You need to create a lambda with no arguments, but which still has its own copy of instance. Hence my answer where you use a function to make the lambda

Comment: @three_pineapples. It works perfectly fine: see my updated answer for a working example. As I explained in my original answer, the default argument is used to cache the loop variable, so there's no need to use a closure (although that will work, too).

Comment: Ah, apologies, I skipped over the `instance=instance` part of it (I just read `instance`). Your method is far cleaner than my suggestion and I'll start using it in my own code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a function using `lambda` where some of the variables inside the function are not being passed in as arguments to the function. When the lambda function is executed, when the signal is emitted, it uses the value of those variables (like `instance`) at that moment in time. To be clear, every lambda function you make is using the value of `instance` at runtime, rather than define time. So `instance` only holds a reference to the object used in the last iteration of our loop, which explains the behaviour you are seeing.

Some useful information can be found here (read the comments too) http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/04/25/passing-extra-arguments-to-pyqt-slot/

From the comments of the above link:

> What you can do is have another function generate the lambda, i.e.
>   something like:
>
> ```
> def make_callback(param):   
>         return lambda: self.on_button(param)
> ```
>
> And in the connection, call `make_callback(i)`. Then a different lambda is
>   created for each iteration.

So you would want to generalise this and pass in things like `instance` to the `make_callback` function and then place your `lambda` definition inside the `make_callback` function. I would provide a clear example of this, but as the other answer says, your formatting appears to have become very messed up in your question and I would likely get it wrong for your specific application. If you aren't following what I've said, make the code in your question clearer and I'll have a go at creating an example!

Answer (score 0):

An example of creating the separate function "make_callback", and passing parameters to it in the for loop. This resolves the issue of only the last lambda function being connected to the instance.

```
for button_widget, button_dict in zip(self.button_widget_dictionary.values(),
                                                  self.button_page_dictionary.values()):
                button_widget.pressed.connect(self.make_callback(button_dict))


def make_callback(self,button_dict):

        return lambda: self.central_widget.add_graph_tab_dict(
            button_dict['Tab_options']['name'][0] + ': ' 
          + button_dict['Tab_options']["graph_title"][0:4] + "...",
            button_dict)
```