# Connect several comboboxes to same signal

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have four different combos like this:

```
cmb_filtermode_1 = QtGui.QComboBox()
cmb_filtermode_1.addItem("High Pass")
cmb_filtermode_1.addItem("Low Pass")
```

I already know how to connect a signal that triggers when an option is selected

```
cmb_filtermode_1.activated.connect( combo_chosen )
```

But that only sends a integer value to the slot. I would like to know if there is possible to get the combo which triggered the signal to have a single slot for all them.

```
def combo_chosen( combo ):
    if combo == 0: #0 is the index of Low-Pass
        #Do something here with the selected value and the combo who triggered
    elif combo == 1: #is the index of High-pass 
        #Do something here with the selected value and the combo who triggered
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, use `sender()` method inside your slot. For example:

```
sender = self.sender()
```

Sender variable contains widget which emitted signal. Good example you can also find [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/eventsandsignals/).

I suppose that you wrote your slot as simple function, not as `QObject`'s subclass method. `sender()` is a method of `QObject`, so you can use this approach only in class.

Your error for example:

```
def buttonClicked(self):

    sender = self.sender()
    sender.setText('2')

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Button 1", self)
        btn1.move(30, 50)

        btn2 = QtGui.QPushButton("Button 2", self)
        btn2.move(150, 50)

        btn1.clicked.connect( buttonClicked)            
        btn2.clicked.connect(buttonClicked)

        self.statusBar()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event sender')
        self.show()


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Correct approach:

```
class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button 1", self)
        btn1.move(30, 50)

        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button 2", self)
        btn2.move(150, 50)

        btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)            
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.statusBar()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event sender')
        self.show()

    def buttonClicked(self):# now it is method

        sender = self.sender()
        sender.setText('2')

def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: "self is not defined"... perhaps i cannot use it on this situation :/

Comment: @Chernobyl, The OP isn't using object oriented design I guess, so, `self` won't be there.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother yourself with the complicated things. You just need to use `lambda` expression to pass the combo to the slot.

```
cmb_filtermode_1 = QtGui.QComboBox()
cmb_filtermode_1.addItem("High Pass")
cmb_filtermode_1.addItem("Low Pass")
cmb_filtermode_1.activated.connect( lambda index: combo_chosen(cmb_filtermode_1) )
```

`lambda` creates an anonymous function, the combo's signal is connected to this function, which calls the actual slot inside it passing the combo object to the slot.

```
def combo_chosen(combo):
    # combo is QComboBox that sent the signal
    print combo.currentText() # prints the selected items text
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `self.sender()` because you want to call a function rather than a method, then you can connect to a `lambda` expression which in turn calls your function, passing in a reference to the combobox.

For example

```
cmb_filtermode_1.activated.connect( lambda index, combobox=cmb_filtermode_1: combo_chosen(index, combobox) )
cmb_filtermode_2.activated.connect( lambda index, combobox=cmb_filtermode_2: combo_chosen(index, combobox) )
```

Now you just adjust the default argument for `combobox` for each one (see example above).

Modify your function accordingly:

```
def combo_chosen( index, combobox ):
    if index == 0: #0 is the index of Low-Pass
        #Do something here with the selected value and the combo who triggered
    elif index == 1: #is the index of High-pass 
        #Do something here with the selected value and the combo who triggered
```

Note: it is important that you keep the `combobox=cmb_filtermode_x` argument as shown (rather than directly passing it to the `combo_chosen` function) in case the variable is reused later to point to a different combobox. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19523242/1994235) covers why you need to do this (though note some of it uses the old signal/slot syntax so may be confusing).