# PyQt - Track Sender for contextMenu

Tags: python, pyqt

What is the way of getting the **Sender** of a right-mouse-click on a QLabel()? I want to know on which Widget the right-mouse-click happened. I have code to get the position, but how can i get the Sender?

Getting the Sender i could retrieve the **accessibleName()**

Here is my current minimal Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import *    #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               

        # qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        label =  QLabel("BG Sessions", self)
        label.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        label.setObjectName("title")
        label.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.clearCache)
        label.move(50, 50)       

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')    
        self.show()

    def clearCache(self, pos):
        print pos


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`self.sender()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender) inside the slot does this job.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use `sender()` as suggested by Alexander Lutsenko  keep this in mind:
[QT-documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender)

> Warning: This function violates the object-oriented principle of modularity. However, getting access to the sender might be useful when many signals are connected to a single slot.

if all widgets sending the signal are from the same type,`findChild()` can be used instead. this is working with my tableViews:

```
# create signalMapper
self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)
self.signalMapper.mapped[str].connect(<slot>)

# connect the widgets with signalMapper
self.<widget>.<yourSignal>.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
self.signalMapper.setMapping(self.<widget>, self.<widget>.objectName())         # sends objectName() to slot

# in slot:
obj = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLabel,objectname)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the way you connect your signal such that you pass in a reference to the object you are connecting the signal from.

For instance:

```
my_object.customContextMenuRequested.connect(lambda pos, obj=my_object: self.clearCache(pos, obj))
```

(you will of course need to modify `clearCache()` so that it accepts this extra argument)

Note: the `obj=my_object` line is not redundant, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19523242/1994235) for details.

Comment: what when i just want to pas obj but not pos? When i am doing that, i am still getting the Position of the object

Comment: The `customContextMenuRequested` signal emits the position, and there is nothing you can do about that. So while you still have to has `pos` as an argument to the `lambda` function, you don't have to pass it to `clearCache` if you don't want to (for example `my_object.customContextMenuRequested.connect(lambda pos, obj=my_object: self.clearCache(obj))`