# pyqt5: passing extra arguments to pyqt slots when connecting in a loop

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Can't understand why this code always shows me the same result: i=4

```
for i in range(0,5):
    self.close_deal[i].clicked.connect(lambda:self.printme(i))
def printme(self,i):
    print('i=',i)
```

but when i write it as:

```
self.close_deal[0].clicked.connect(lambda:self.printme(0))
self.close_deal[1].clicked.connect(lambda:self.printme(1))
self.close_deal[2].clicked.connect(lambda:self.printme(2))
self.close_deal[3].clicked.connect(lambda:self.printme(3))
self.close_deal[4].clicked.connect(lambda:self.printme(4))
```

i receive different results

Comment: `lambda *args, i=i: self.printme(i)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QtCore.QObject.connect in a loop only affects the last instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510860/qtcore-qobject-connect-in-a-loop-only-affects-the-last-instance)