# PyQt4: Signal slot mechanism doesn't work correctly for 'List of buttons'

Tags: python, qt, lambda, pyqt, pyqt4

I need to put 6 buttons on the window for my application. But as the application grows, more buttons might be needed (maybe 7, 8, ..). That is why I put those buttons in a Python list. Below you can see my code. You can simply copy/paste it, and it should run on your system without any errors:

[image]

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

def setCustomSize(x, width, height):
    sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(x.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    x.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    x.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(width, height))
    x.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(width, height))

''''''

class CustomMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(CustomMainWindow, self).__init__()

        # Define the geometry of the main window
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("my first window")

        # Create FRAME_A
        self.FRAME_A = QtGui.QFrame(self)
        self.FRAME_A.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" % QtGui.QColor(210,210,235,255).name())
        self.LAYOUT_A = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.LAYOUT_A.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.FRAME_A.setLayout(self.LAYOUT_A)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.FRAME_A)

        # Place the buttons
        self.placeButtons()

        self.show()

    ''''''

    def placeButtons(self):
        self.btn = []

        for i in range(6):
            self.btn.append(QtGui.QPushButton(text = 'btn[' + str(i) + ']'))
            setCustomSize(self.btn[i], 100, 50)
            self.btn[i].clicked.connect(lambda: self.btnAction(i))            
            self.LAYOUT_A.addWidget(self.btn[i])

        ''''''

    ''''''


    def btnAction(self,n):
        print("btn[" + str(n) + "] is clicked")

    ''''''



''' End Class '''



if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Plastique'))
    myGUI = CustomMainWindow()


    sys.exit(app.exec_())

''''''
```

I use the standard signal/slot mechanism to connect each button to the `btnAction(self,n)` function. As you can see, I use a special feature - lets call it the `lambda` feature - to pass on a parameter. The parameter is the button number.

Unfortunately, I get the following outputs, no matter what button I push:

```
>>> btn[5] is clicked
>>> btn[5] is clicked
>>> btn[5] is clicked
>>> btn[5] is clicked
```

I changed the `placeButtons(self)` function into:

```
    def placeButtons(self):
        self.btn = []

        for i in range(6):
            self.btn.append(QtGui.QPushButton(text = 'btn[' + str(i) + ']'))
            setCustomSize(self.btn[i], 100, 50)
            if(i==0):
                self.btn[i].clicked.connect(lambda: self.btnAction(0))
            elif(i==1):
                self.btn[i].clicked.connect(lambda: self.btnAction(1))
            elif(i==2):
                self.btn[i].clicked.connect(lambda: self.btnAction(2))
            elif(i==3):
                self.btn[i].clicked.connect(lambda: self.btnAction(3))
            elif(i==4):
                self.btn[i].clicked.connect(lambda: self.btnAction(4))
            elif(i==5):
                self.btn[i].clicked.connect(lambda: self.btnAction(5))

            self.LAYOUT_A.addWidget(self.btn[i])

        ''''''

    ''''''
```

Now I get the correct output:

```
>>> btn[0] is clicked
>>> btn[1] is clicked
>>> btn[2] is clicked
>>> btn[3] is clicked
```

So the new `placeButtons(self)` function kind of works, but it's just so inefficient and cumbersome. Does anyone know what was wrong with the first (and cleaner) implementation?

Note: I work on Windows 10, use Python v3 and make my GUI with the PyQt4 library (anaconda package).

**EDIT**

Thank you mr. salomonderossi. Now your solution works! I first have to import the functools:

```
import functools
```

Next I apply your solution:

```
    def placeButtons(self):
        self.btn = []

        for i in range(6):
            self.btn.append(QtGui.QPushButton(text = 'btn[' + str(i) + ']'))
            setCustomSize(self.btn[i], 100, 50)
            self.btn[i].clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.btnAction, i))
            self.LAYOUT_A.addWidget(self.btn[i])

        ''''''

    ''''''
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QtCore.QObject.connect in a loop only affects the last instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510860/qtcore-qobject-connect-in-a-loop-only-affects-the-last-instance)

Comment: Hi @three_pineapples , it looks like my question is indeed very similar to "qtcore-qobject-connect-..". Thank you for pointing this out. Nevertheless, I think that my question should stay on StackOverflow. I gave a complete code example that people can copy-paste into their own Python IDE, and try out. I believe that gives some added value. Secondly, the other question doesn't contain the important keywords "signal-slot mechanism". That is probably the reason why I did not find it when googling for answers. What do you think?

Comment: Duplicate questions aren't deleted. The point is actually to provide a variety of entry points that can be found with different search terms but to have a single place for answers (so that if the answer needs to change one day, you don't have to update 50 different question answers!) But chances are my duplicate flag won't get the required number of votes anyway...

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you for the clarification :-)
I'm pretty new on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the value for each created (lambda) function. To do that, you can pass them as parameter with a default value:

```py
for i in range(6):
    self.btn[i].clicked.connect(lambda i=i: self.btnAction(i))
```

Here is a minimal example to show the effect:

```py
def test_function(x):
    return x


def test():
    # DO NOT USE THIS. This is just for showing the effect
    wrong = list()
    for i in range(6):
        wrong.append(lambda: test_function(i))

    for w in wrong:
        print(w())  # will always print 5

    print("-"*10)
    # This is the desired behaviour
    right = list()
    for i in range(6):
        right.append(lambda i=i: test_function(i))

    for r in right:
        print(r())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Which gives the following output:

```
5
5
5
5
5
5
----------
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Alternatively you can use [partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) from the functools package:

```
for i in range(6):
    self.btn[i].clicked.connect(partial(self.btnAction, i))
```

Comment: Hi mr. salomonderossi. Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've posted an **EDIT** to show how I implemented your solution, and what output I get.

Comment: @K.Mulier You are right. I do not know why the functions prints False in this case. I updated my answer and tested the solution with `partial` and it works fine

Comment: Thanks to your help, I can finish my project now :-)